# How to calculate the capacitance needed to reduce oscillations in this circuit?

Tags: mosfet, dc, resonance, oscillation

The following circuit is part of a DC current driver for a Helmholtz coil (L2,RL2), the circuits for Vreg and Vin work as intended so I am pretty sure that the oscillation is coming from this side of the circuit.

[image]
[image]
I am guessing the parasitic capacitance of the Power MOSFET is interacting with L2 to create the oscillations seen in the oscilloscope but I cannot tell for sure if that is the case, as varying C1 (using C3 for that) also reduces the oscillations of the circuit. Placing a sufficiently large C2 in parallel to L2 seems to do the trick as well but I am not sure how should I calculate the exact value to get rid of the oscillations.

I quite a newbie at this so I am not sure if my explanation and the proposed solutions are correct, I also thought about taking the LC resonant frequency formula to 0 and calculating the value of the capacitor but I am not sure if that is how I am supposed to solve this issue, any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is C1, why is it there? Why is R5 so large? What's U3 GBW and other vital parameters? What are Q1 capacitances?

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned that this circuit is based on Libbrecht-Hall's laser diode current driver, I adapted it to obtain higher output currents. A figure of the schematics can be found here: https://authors.library.caltech.edu/29621/1/LIBrsi93.pdf the C1, R6 and R5 are meant to reduce the bandwidth of the circuit (I'm not sure if it is relevant for my application), and I will be using a AD8671 opamp (10MHz GBW), Q1 capacitances are Ciss 500pF, Coss 150pF, and Crss 50pF

Comment: 'reducing the bandwidth' within a feedback loop is a good formula for creating oscillation, especially if the other devices are rolling off at similar frequencies. As you already have your circuit in a simulator, it would be good to break the loop and see how your phase shift and gain builds up round the loop - that is, do the Bode plot. If your FET is significantly different to the VP0106, then you might have loop instability. Did you notice how the diagram in LIBrsi93 was nicely drawn 'positive to the top'. Try replacing L2 with a resistor to check just the opamp/FET part of the circuit

Comment: Bandwidth is reduced by increasing negative feedback around the amplifier: add a resistor from Rs1 to -IN and then a R+C from OUT to -IN. You may also want an R+C across the load, to dampen its resonance with Coss.

Comment: Simplify your circuit first. Get rid of that R5 and R6 network and re-add (or change) components as you see fit with regards to stability.

Comment: I increased the negative feedback as Tim said and checked the opamp/fet part of the circuit by like @Neil_Uk said, so far no oscillations until I add the inductor back, I did what Ernesto said as well and changing the R5 to 800 ohms or lower removed the oscillations and removing all the three components crashes the simulation. Something is going on that I'm unable to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent a lot of time on this answer, because I'm curious about driving inductive loads in this current source arrangement. There are probably errors which I'll fix as they are pointed out, but this should give you an idea of my thinking, regarding stabilising the system.

Let me redraw the salient parts of your circuit the "right" way up, so it's easier to envisage the potentials:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi3jhN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first thing to do is get an idea of the stability of this thing, which we can do by opening the loop, biasing the system near some quiescent mid-point, and running a frequency analysis on the gain from input to feedback, the so called "loop gain":

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSygH9.png)</sup>

[image]
[image]

Phase is shifted -180°, meaning that feedback has become positive, when gain is still well over 0dB (unity). It's completely unstable, right off the bat.

I hope it's obvious that that actual 0dB phase will vary depending on op-amp and MOSFET models, so you'll have to perform this procedure for your own particular setup.

We require gain to be unity while phase shift is well under 180°. I suggest aiming for 0dB gain at 135°, giving you a phase margin of 45°. From those graphs, that occurs at about 10kHz.

One way to achieve that would be to simply attenuate the op-amp output with a resistor divider. At 10kHz, gain is currently about +45dB. I will need to change loop gain by about -45dB (÷180) to make this loop stable:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKX9Jt.png)</sup>

[image]
[image]

The problem with this solution is loop gain is now under 60dB (×1000), which means you lose a little linearity between input reference potential and voltage across R1. It's still within 0.1% or so, though. This approach does have the advantages of simplicity without compromising bandwidth.

If you wish to keep loop gain at DC as high as possible, then you must find another way to get phase shift under 135° for all gains above 0dB. Looking again at the bode plots above, I see phase taking a plunge above about 1kHz. This can be mitigated with a phase compensator, which effectively adds a zero in the transfer function, boosting gain beyond a certain frequency.

Passive compensation between the op-amp output and the MOSFET's gate would not be ideal here, because any additional impedance in that path would slow the charging of the MOSFET's gate capacitance. I'll stick with an active one, requiring another op-amp:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmt3Q7.png)</sup>

I've set the compensator (blue box) to have a break frequency of about 1.6kHz, (\$f_{BREAK} \approx \frac{1}{2\pi R_3 C_1}\$ for \$R_3 >> R_4\$) where it will introduce a phase *lead* of 45° mitigating the phase lag of the loop so far.

Repeating the loop-gain test with this phase compensator in place:

[image]
[image]

Phase shift never approaches 180° in either direction for gains above 0dB. I'm a little worried about behaviour to the right of the marker, but I don't want to spend a week on this, so I'm going to call it done. Here's how the circuit performed with *no* compensation, fed with a 10mV square input:

[image]

This is the response with compensation in place:

[image]

We are not done yet, though, because all the above has to do with small signals, and we haven't considered what happens when your inductive load suffers large swings in voltage.

The load, being an inductor, with its own resistance, and the 3Ω in series with it, is simply unable to change its current instantly, like a capacitor or resistor could. We can calculate the maximum rate of change of current through such an inductance, with a sudden change of 12V applied across it. Maximum current will be:

$$ I_{MAX} = \frac{12V}{3\Omega} = 4A $$

Maximum (initial) rate of change of current:

$$ \frac{dI}{dt} = I_{MAX}\frac{R}{L} = 4A \times \frac{3\Omega}{1.8mH} = 6.7kAs^{-1} $$

The importance of this figure is that if you attempt to change current through the inductor faster than this, the voltage across it will change immediately by *at least* 12V, up or down depending on whether the change in current is an increase or decrease.

This is why people put diodes across relay coils; when the current path is interrupted, the coil can respond with hundreds of volts of change across it, destroying the MOSFET that switched it off. Your load, I notice, doesn't have that protection, and I strongly recommend you include one.

This behaviour means that even the slightest change at the MOSFET's gate can produce large voltage changes across the load which are well outside the realm of "small signals", and which will render useless much of the above measures we have employed. Drain potential can easily rise to the point of clipping, and fall to the point of destroying the MOSFET. I suspect you can even turn negative feedback into positive if drain potential rises sufficiently to interfere with the MOSFET's ability to act as a source follower.

I don't know what the real-life consequences are, because honestly I've never implemented a voltage-controlled current source like this with an inductive load.

However, one thing seems clear to me, and I may be wrong, but you will have to limit the rate of change of input control voltage to match the maximum possible rate of change of current in the load, if you want to avoid nasty surprises.

This could be done inside the control loop, but it might introduce a further phase lag requiring further compensation. Thankfully it's easy to implement at the input, outside the loop.

First we calculate the transconductance \$\$ of the system, the ratio between input voltage and output current.

$$ g = \frac{I_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = \frac{1}{250m\Omega} = 4AV^{-1} $$

Now we can find out what rate of change of input voltage corresponds to 6.7kA per second of change in output current:

$$ \frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{6.7kAs^{-1}}{4AV^{-1}} = 1.7kVs^{-1} $$

To limit the rate of change of input potential we can use a simple low-pass RC filter. I'll assume that the maximum current you will command will be 4A, corresponding to an input amplitude of 1V. The maximum rate of change across an initially uncharged capacitor in an RC filter, with 1V across it is:

$$ \frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{1V}{RC} < 1.7kVs^{-1} $$

Find values for R and C that satisfy this, such as 6kΩ and 100nF, and place the filter in front of the entire setup:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ8Ik4.png)</sup>

I also included a couple of diodes to dump the inductor's energy as quickly as possible, when it develops −12V.

Here's the sense voltage (top, orange), and inductor current (bottom, blue), when driven with a square 100Hz, 800mV peak-to-peak input (top, blue)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why is your R7 in 3rd schematic wired to ground?

Comment: @Antonio51 that's a good question. It would probably be better to +12V, to keep the op-amp output closer to mid-range.

Comment: @Antonio51 I never checked if the op-amp output is even between 0V and 12V, so this divider might not even be feasible.

Comment: Ok ... It was just a question.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive reply, I was thinking about the accumulated emf of the inductor that you mentioned so I added a 1N4002 to the simulation in the meantime. I noticed you added a zener as well, how does that increase the circuit protection in comparison to just having a single diode?

Comment: @EEnoob When back EMF is limited to 1V or so, by a single diode, the power dissipated in the diode will be \$P=V \times I = 1V\times I\$. By allowing back EMF to rise to 13V (1V + 12V across the two diodes) we still protect the transistor, but now the power dissipated is \$P=13V\times I\$, for the same current, so coil energy is absorbed 13 times faster. You must of course do the numbers to check the zener diode can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that OP's picture schematic has a "strange" behavior ...
(Deny dcof ... used as a parameter from 0.5 to 1V).
Only changed R5 (my R1) -> 100 Ohm, C2 (my C3) -> 1n.

[image]